# My bootstrap is not working properly within my js file

Tags: javascript, html, json, bootstrap-4

How would I make it so every new data entered in the array the "col-sm-6" would be next to each other instead of continuing to go under each other ( this is a js file with writtent html in the form of bootstrap)

```js
const collegeData = [{
    name: "University of Pennsylvania",
    photo: "/Pages/About-Us Photos/yashviVardhan.png",
    major: "Major: Biology",
    minor: "Minor: Business",
  },
  {
    name: "University of Chicago",
    photo: "/Pages/About-Us Photos/yashVardhan.png",
    major: "Major: Mechanical Engineering",
    minor: "Minor: Business",
  }
];

window.onload = function loadWindow() {

  document.getElementById('adf').innerHTML = `${collegeData.length}
    ${collegeData.map(function(college){
      return `
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Pages/Colleges.css">
        <script src="Colleges.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
      <div class="row">
        <!-- College Advisor -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img class="college-photo" src= "${college.photo}">
        <h2> ${college.name}</h2>
        <h3> ${college.major}</h3>
        <h3> ${college.minor}</h3>
       </div>
      </div>
      </div>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Pages/Colleges.css">
        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Colleges.js"></script>
      </body>
      `}).join("")}`
};
```

Comment: Did you try inspecting it in the browser as to where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and i don't see any issue. can you recreate your issue? expand the code snippet to see it working properly.

```html
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2> college.name
      </h2>
      <h3> college.major
      </h3>
      <h3> college.minor
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2> college.name
      </h2>
      <h3> college.major
      </h3>
      <h3> college.minor
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2> college.name
      </h2>
      <h3> college.major
      </h3>
      <h3> college.minor
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2> college.name
      </h2>
      <h3> college.major
      </h3>
      <h3> college.minor
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h2> college.name
      </h2>
      <h3> college.major
      </h3>
      <h3> college.minor
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Since im pulling information from the array everytime the html runs for the new imformation in the array it drops a line